# Validate this input with "+" symbol only

Tags: html

i have a `<input type="text" id="phone-request">`. I want to validate this input with "+" symbol only can type once in first of input, and allow user type number only like this https://numverify.com/.

Comment: On SO, you are expected to try to **write the code yourself**. After **[doing more research](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592)** if you have a problem you can **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and providing a **[Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)** within the question itself.

Comment: Try it with the pattern attr [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_pattern.asp)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Found answer with regex: /^[0-9+][0-9]{1,}[0-9]$/

Answer (score 0):

You can use [cleave](https://nosir.github.io/cleave.js/):

```
    var cleavePhone = new Cleave('#phone-request', {
       phone: true,
       phoneRegionCode: 'US'
    });
```